# Google Maps API: Get only street name and number

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I use the Google Maps API and so far I have only used formatted_address to output the result of my geocoding function. How do I need to modify my function in order to get **ONLY the name of the street and the number?** I want to insert them into an input field.

My current function looks like this:

```
function getAndDisplayNewAddress(position) {

     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    // Find out longitude and latitude
    geocoder.geocode({
            'latLng' : position
    }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                 $('#display_of_street').val(results[0].formatted_address);

             }
    });

 }; // /function getAndDisplayStreet()
```

Answer (score -1):

:) results is object you can follow on this site :)

in here you can see it:  http://jsfiddle.net/HoangHieu/x8dSP/3631/

```
function reverseGeocodeResult(results, status) {
    currentReverseGeocodeResponse = results;
    if (status == 'OK') {
    if (results.length == 0) {
             $('#id of element').val(results[0].formatted_address);
    }
}
```

like

```
 {
     "address_components": [{
         "long_name": "192",
         "short_name": "192",
         "types": ["street_number"]
     }, {
         "long_name": "An Dương Vương",
         "short_name": "An Dương Vương",
         "types": ["route"]
     }, {
         "long_name": "phường 3",
         "short_name": "phường 3",
         "types": ["sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political"]
     }, {
         "long_name": "Ho Chi Minh City",
         "short_name": "Ho Chi Minh City",
         "types": ["locality", "political"]
     }, {
         "long_name": "Quận 5",
         "short_name": "Quận 5",
         "types": ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]
     }, {
         "long_name": "Hồ Chí Minh",
         "short_name": "Hồ Chí Minh",
         "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
     }, {
         "long_name": "Vietnam",
         "short_name": "VN",
         "types": ["country", "political"]
     }],
     "formatted_address": "192 An Dương Vương, phường 3, Quận 5, Hồ Chí Minh, Vietnam",
     "geometry": {
         "bounds": {
             "xa": {
                 "k": 10.7576423,
                 "j": 10.7576594
             },
             "pa": {
                 "j": 106.6744804,
                 "k": 106.67448660000002
             }
         },
         "location": {
             "k": 10.7576423,
             "B": 106.67448660000002
         },
         "location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
         "viewport": {
             "xa": {
                 "k": 10.7563018697085,
                 "j": 10.7589998302915
             },
             "pa": {
                 "j": 106.67313451970847,
                 "k": 106.67583248029155
             }
         }
     },
     "types": ["street_address"]
 }
```

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/HoangHieu/x8dSP/3631/)